# Use polar coordinates to find the volume of the given solid

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, polar-coordinates

Use polar coordinates to find the volume of the given solid bounded by the paraboloid $z=1+2x^2+2y^2$ and the plane $z=7$ in the first octant.

I did it. Is that right ?

$$\int_0^{\pi \over 2} \int_0^{\sqrt{3}}(7-(1+2r^2))r dr d\theta = \frac{9\pi}{4} $$

Thanks

Comment: but can't we do like this? $2*x^2+2*y^2+1=7$ so  we have   $x^2+y^2=6$ or $x^2+y^2=3$  from which we get $R=\sqrt{3}$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Answer:

You are almost right except that the integrand is ($7-(1+2r^2)$) = $(6-2r^2)$

Comment: Why is it the reverse order in integrand ? The paraboloid isn't under of the plane ?

Comment: Oops, I changed it

Comment: @satishramanathan can we express it using  circle area?

Comment: Ok. Anyway Thank you for helping : )

Comment: @Ewin  i  tried  to use  circle method,i think it is wrong right?

Comment: @dato Could you show me what did you do ?

Comment: i have answered below you can see

Comment: you're right until you calculate the area of the circle that would be $3\pi$, but under this area it is has variable height of the paraboloid.

Comment: i see,thanks for pointing it,i will delete it